# What software supports BSSID for Intel Wireless N Cards

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have an Intel N 6200 Wireless Card and I need a wireless network profile manager/connector that supports BSSID because I have multiple networks with the same SSID but different network Keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WirelessMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/wirelessmonitor.htm) can do it but is unfortunately a commercial package.  You do get a 30 day trial and has helped me avoid a misconfigured BTFON AP in my area.  If I find another preferably free alternative I'll update this thread